its side or his side
I'm looking for help on a support site, one of my answers was:

Will wait response from Apple support, I am sure this problem is from its side

I'm not sure if this sentence is well formed or not, or if I should use "his" instead of "its"

Will wait response from Apple support, I am sure this problem is from his side

Thanks!

Note that there are other errors in this sentence. Even in chat-speak, you can't use "wait" like that; it must be "wait for".

Please check your basic grammar: Wait for something.

It's wait for... or await..., and normally we'd expect an article with ...a response in such contexts.

Some things are unclear in this question. 1) "... one of my answers" Do you mean an answer that was given to you? Or one that you gave to others? 2) It's hard to be sure of the meaning without more context. I'm guessing that someone else told you that the problem seems to "from Apple's side," i.e. something the company is responsible for. In which case, a company isn't a "he." But we can't be sure that's what's meant without more context. Please edit to tell more.

Why don't you tell us what his/its is referring to? Is it Apple? Apple support? Someone at Apple? Somewhere else entirely?

Why negative votes? It is obvious English is not my native language, so it’s difficult for me to express in a more clear way.

By the way, I am talking about Apple, Apple support has been friendly and interested on my case.

You would only use "his" for a particular person (and if you knew they were male). In this case "its" is better but "their" is best. "They/their" can refer to an organisation or a particular person of unknown gender [and this is a long standing usage in the English language]. "His" is always wrong for anything other than a single living creature.

@timechessish   Allow a minor quibble! "His" is also quite acceptable for appropriate images in paintings/photos and the like, and for elements of statues. And if you've been around as long as I have, "her" is suitable for a variety of cars, ships and aircraft. My old car would blanch as an "its".
